# get max value based on rank fucntion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sample data like below.

```
entity  account amount  id
ac     1394     156.00  3453
ac    2512      100.00  3453
ac    2512     -70.00   3453
ac    1315     -156.00  3453
ac    1315     156.00   3453
```

I need to show the total sum from amount column irrespective of account column and need to get account which has maximum value in the amount column.

I used the below script for the same. I am able to get the account which has maximum value in the amount column but total sum is not correct. The total sum should be 186 in this case.

```
 select a.account, a.total from (
    select account,sum(amount) as total,
    rank() over (partition by id order by sum(amount) desc) as rank
    from test1
    group by account,id) a
where rank=1
```

the output of above query is

```
account total
1394    156.00
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: what DBMS are you using? and what would be the expected output of your query?

Comment: the total should be 186 that comes from sum of both accounts 1394 and 2512.

Comment: using sql server

Comment: the inner query give the below output

Comment: account total       rank
1394 156.00 1
2512 30.00 2
1315 0.00         3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the requirements, you could use a window function to get the total sum() without partitioning, and then apply a clause with a `row_number()` function order by `amount desc`:

```sql
with windows as (
    select
      account,
      sum(amount) over () as total_sum_amount,
      row_number() over (order by amount desc) as rn
    from test1
)
select
    account,
    total_sum_amount
from windows
where rn = 1;
```

**Output:**

```
account total
1394    186.00
```